# Why java Class<?> is generic but Field is not?

Tags: java, generics

Why java `Class<?>` is generic but `Field` is not?

And class in `java.beans` are not generic such as: `BeanInfo`, `PropertyDescriptor`...

When to use generic class? And I want to design a class to represent java bean / pojo (similar as `BeanInfo`), should I use generic?

Answer (score 0):

Generic types in Java are classes or interfaces and not fields or methods. I think that is why a `Class` is generic and a `Field` is not.

My suggestion is for you to write the interface for your class and if you see that you need to pass `Object` around and do casting, then the generic types should be used.